# fingertip detection and tracking

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

i am working on a project detecting and tracking fingers. Though i find there is quiet a lot resource on this task, i haven't found a effective one yet :(.

So far i have thought of methods to detect hands as follow:

1. Haar training. But firstly we don't have a trained set(xml) as that in the face detection. Secondly, if we do the training ourselves, we don't have enough samples (i am still a college student)
2. skin color detection in HSV space. I have tried this one but the result has a lot of noises so cannot helps me continue the further detection on fingertip.

3.use Handvu. But i have heart that this lib is hard to set up and used in windows...

So in a word, can anyone give me any suggestions on how to detect hands effectively? (After that i may consider about detecting fingertips..)

Thanks!!

Comment: Try to migrate this question to Signal Processing.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.cse.unr.edu/~amayeh/index_files/papers/cviu09.pdf) is a pretty in-depth paper on finger segmentation using Zernike moments. [Here](http://peanuts.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~scan33/plugin-00055109.pdf) is a good paper on using Zernike moments for image recognition as a basis for the first paper.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more about your experimental setup? Are you trying to track fingers against a cluttered background, or a plain cardboard sheet?

1. Haar like features perform very well for face recognition (the Viola Jones paper being a classic example) however I would not recommend them for your task. Although they can be computed fast using the integral image, they work well using a CASCADED Adaboost classification framework.
2. For skin colour detection, it depends on your setup. As a first step you could try doing background subtraction: simply learn the distribution (histogram) of pixels for foreground (ie. the hand) and the background and use these to do image segmentation.
3. I don't know what Handvu is

Zernike moments are also very good shape descriptors that are rotation invariant and can be made to be both scale and translation invariant.

I hope this helps!